# "Mute microphone" native button doesn't work - MSI Modern 15 A10M-214XFR

Tags: sound, shortcut-keys, microphone, msi

I recently bought an MSI Modern 15 A10M-214XFR and installed Kubuntu 20.04. There is just this little problem I can't solve: the "mute mic" native button and associated light (see picture) don't work (the esc light works fine, the other shortcuts too).

[image: light]

I've replaced it with a `amixer set Capture cap`,  but this is not what I'm looking for.

- In settings, Shortcuts, Global Shortcuts, "mute microphone" action is associated with "Microphone Mute" as well as the other actions
- when I run `xev` in a terminal my "mute microphone" key is not detected.

Would someone know how to fix this?

Comment: I forgot to upload the pic : https://imgur.com/a/bExWcqL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this laptop uses some custom WMI events to implement this feature. Unfortunately the Linux driver for this does not seem to support this key. There is unfortunately no way to fix this as an end user, someone needs to add support to this to the Linux kernel.

For anyone interested in adding driver support themselves:
The relevant Linux source file is https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/platform/x86/msi-wmi.c. The C# program driving this feature on Windows is located at C:\Program Files (x86)\MSI\MSI NBFoundation Service\OmApSvcBroker.exe.